# Bing map not getting loaded in Chrome

Tags: openlayers, bing-maps

Bing map is not getting loaded.
Below code written:

```
this.layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: 'Bing Maps aerial',
  type: 'base',
  visible: false,
  source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
    culture: "en-GB",
    key: '123adaf',
    imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels'        
  })
})
```

OSM, Stamen, etc are all working fine but BingMap is not.
I am using Chrome version: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
Is it that BingMaps do not show up in Chrome ?
How do i resolve this?

Comment: Is possible to create a sample Jsfiddle or anywhere.. where we can reproduce the same error or see whatever you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps works fine in Chrome. The Bing Maps layer in Open Layers also appears to work fine in Chrome as well: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html

Check the network requests and look for a request to the Bing Maps imagery service to see if it is responding without any errors. If an error is occurring, there may be an issue with your Bing maps key or account. Here is an example of what the Bing Maps imagery service request URL looks like:

https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Metadata/AerialWithLabels?uriScheme=https&include=ImageryProviders&key=YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY